Akka CoordinatedShutdown BeforeServiceUnbind task not ending before termination on Young Cluster Node
I'm having an issue with Akka CoordinatedShutdown with multiple cluster nodes.
For testing in a local environment I  set up the application to create a cluster from 2 JVM  instances running on fixed ports.  It's also a spring-boot application to expose some API.
The application is composed by N (configurable) workers , 1 root actor (the one created for initializing the ActorSystem with a specific root behaviour) and a SingletonActor that orchestrate the work to be done to the worker actors, and receive the completition or error routines from the worker.
During instance initialization the worker are created and then added to the Receptionist, as they are managed with a RoundRobinRouter, then a RegisterWorkers message was sent to the service, using the ask pattern to ensure the message is delivered.
Then we need to manage when an instance go down, and for this scope the CoordinatedShutdown seems the ideal functionality. So I used
 CoordinatedShutdown.get(actorSystem).addTask(CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseBeforeUnbind(), "shutdownHook", () -> {
    shutdownHook();
    return CompletableFuture.completedStage(Done.done());
});

shutdownHook deregister the instance workers from the Receptionist, send a DeregisterWorkers message to the service, always using the ask pattern. Until this moment everything works well.
Then it send a termination directive to the workers. This message  have 2 way:

If the actor is done, or it wasn't even started, the handler reply that the worker is Shutdown after setting an internal flag.
If the actor is processing, it interrupt the operation on the actor itself, and send a failed message to the service, allowing the service to count that processing between the terminated ones.
This part is problematic. While it works if the shutdown is executing on the same cluster node of the singleton actor, other nodes experience 2 issues.

Here is the first problem. If the workers are on another member of the cluster respect the SingletonActor, the service, the worker do send this message to the service, but the service doesn't process it in short time, but only after all other workers ended their processing or a shutdown procedure is initiated on this node, that could happen even after some minutes after the shutdown.
I would expect these messages to be processed in short time, max some seconds, considering that this actor doesn't receive many messages (1 for instance up, 1 for instance down, 1 for worker processing (processing that can take minutes), and few for checking the service status (from the spring boot controller, API triggered)).
Another issue is that in this part of the code Akka will sometime exit way to early.
In the hook there is a loop that send the Shutdown command the actor, and expect an answer. If the returned value is OK (meaning that the work is not processing) the worker is removed from the list of instance worker, if it return WAIT, it keep the worker around to retry after the cycle.
This procedure use Await.result on a DefaultPromise from scala to block the hook execution until the actor answer.
List<ActorRef<Worker.Command>> activeWorkers = new ArrayList();
while(workers.isEmpty()){  //workers is defined globally, assigned at initialization
    workers.foreach( worker -> {
        Promise.DefaultPromise<Boolean> promise = new Promise.DefaultPromise<>(); 
        actorSystem.log().error("Shut down actor {}", worker.path().name());
        context.ask(Worker.ShutdownStatus.class, worker, Duration.ofSecond(20),
            Worker.ShutdownActor::new, (resp, thr) -> {
                if(resp == ShutdownStatus.OK){
                    promise.success(false);
                    actorSystem.log().error("Actor shut down {}", worker.path().name());
                } 
                else {
                    promise.success(true);
                    actorSystem.log().error("Actor still busy {}", worker.path().name());
                }
                return new Nil(); /*Dummy command with no processing on the calling actor side*/ 
            }
        ); 
        boolean res = Await.result(promise, Duration.create(21, TimeUnit.SECONDS));  //For brevity the handling of the exceptions isn't written here. also this Duration is the scala class. 
        if(res){
            activeWorkers.add(worker);
        }
    });
    workers.removeIf( el -> !activeWork.contains(el));
    activeWork.clear();
}
actorSystem.log().error("All workers down. End hook");

Yet this code often doesn't  execute in its entirety. The last logged message many times doesn't get executed at all ,unless all workers are already "Done"
I also did try to send all ShutdownStatus and only then AWAITing on the promise
Note there is no timout here. Timout for the stage is setted manually to an higher time then the time the application exit after the shutdown is initiated.
The ShutdownActor message is handled in this way in the worker
    boolean isShutdown = this.shutdown.getandSet(true);
    if(workDone.get()) {
        shutdown.resp.tell(ShutdownStatus.OK);
        return Behaviors.stopped();
    }
    if(!isShutdown) {
        killswitch.shutdown();
        getContext().ask(Service.AckChunk.class, replyTo  , Duration.ofSeconds(10), //ReplyTo is the server singleton
            res -> Service.Failed(res),
            (ret,thr) -> {
                workDone.set(true);
                return new Nil();
            }
    }
    shutdown.resp.tell(ShutdownStatus.WAIT);
    return Behaviors.same();
}

